# Sql to change the column sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dense-rank

How to change the old sequence in the column  to new in using sql server 2005

```
old new
   1   1
   1   1
   3   2
   4   3
   5   4
   5   4
   5   4
   8   5
   8   5
   10  6
```

Comment: the first row has to be 1

Comment: "the first row has to be 1 –". Then you should be able to edit your question to correct it. Also,  I am not sure what you are asking. You want to "renumber" the the values within an INT column removing gapes and preserving order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [window function `dense_rank()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) without a `PARTITION` clause:

```
SELECT old, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY old) AS new
FROM   tbl;
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `dense_rank` as it would maintain the correct sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `dense_rank`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by old) rn, old
from yourtable
order by old
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3428/4)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [**DENSE_RANK**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)()

```
SELECT
    T.*
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T.Old) As New
FROM Table1 T
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c072/3)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to use `partition by` in this case.